# Reproject Canary Islands sf data to the same projection of Spain boundary map using mapSpain in R

Tags: r, leaflet, r-sf

I have a sf object with some drought data of Spain, and I want to project this data into a leaflet map. The data source is: https://www.miteco.gob.es/es/biodiversidad/temas/desertificacion-restauracion/lucha-contra-la-desertificacion/lch_pand_descargas.aspx

I am using the function `esp_get_country()` from the library *mapSpain*, to get the boundaries of the country.

The problem is that, in the sf object, Canary Islands are represented far away from the boundary map. How can I project Canary Islands polygons from the sf as they are in the boundary map?

I have tried the functions `st_crs()` to get the crs from the boundary map and the function `st_transform()` to reproject the sf object, but it didn't do anything.

The code I am using is this:

```
# get the boundary map from package 'mapSpain'
spain_coun_sf <- esp_get_country()

# import the drought data from Canary Islands (extraction of the whole drought data)
drought_data_canarias <- readOGR(
  dsn = path,
  layer = "pand_c",
  verbose = FALSE
)

drought_data_canarias <- st_as_sf(drought_data_canarias)

drought_data_canarias <- st_transform(drought_data_canarias , crs = st_crs(spain_coun_sf))

leaflet(spain_coun_sf) %>% addPolygons() %>% addPolygons(data = deser_sf_canarias)
```

Comment: `st_transform(your_sf, epsg_code)`, example: `data_reprojected <- st_transform(drought_data_canarias, 3857)` (3857 = EPSG code for "Google Mercator")

Comment: Hello, and thank you for your answer. I have set the same EPSG code for both of the objects:
```spain_coun_sf <- st_transform(spain_coun_sf, 3857)``` and ```data_reprojected <- st_transform(drought_data_canarias, 3857)```
But when I try to plot them together I still see Canary Island map far away from the boundary map. Any help?

Comment: please see answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

creator of mapSpain speaking.

You can avoid the displacement of the Canary Island using the option `moveCAN = FALSE`. This is available in all the functions of the package, and all the doc packages have an specific section about this:

https://ropenspain.github.io/mapSpain/reference/esp_get_country.html#displacing-the-canary-islands

> **Displacing the Canary Islands**
>
> While `moveCAN` is useful for visualization, it would alter the actual geographic position of the Canary Islands. When using the output for spatial analysis or using tiles (e.g. with `esp_getTiles()` or `addProviderEspTiles()`) this option should be set to `FALSE` in order to get the actual coordinates, instead of the modified ones.

See a full reprex here. Since you use Canarias layer only I recommend you to use `esp_get_ccaa("Canarias", moveCAN = FALSE)` to focus only on that CCAA:

```r
library(mapSpain)
library(ggplot2)

spain_coun_sf_nomoved <- esp_get_country()

ggplot(spain_coun_sf_nomoved) +
  geom_sf()
```

[image]

```r
# Deactivate

spain_coun_sf <- esp_get_country(moveCAN = FALSE)

ggplot(spain_coun_sf) +
  geom_sf()
```

[image]

```r
# Your reprex, use CCAA instead to focus in Canarias

canarias <- esp_get_ccaa("Canarias", moveCAN = FALSE)

# Download file

tempfile <- tempfile(fileext = ".zip")

download.file("https://www.miteco.gob.es/es/biodiversidad/servicios/banco-datos-naturaleza/0904712280184ea3_tcm30-177178.zip", tempfile)

unzip(tempfile, junkpaths = TRUE, exdir = tempdir())

library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.9.1, GDAL 3.2.1, PROJ 7.2.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE

file_path <- list.files(tempdir(), pattern = "shp$", full.names = TRUE)

drought_data_canarias <- st_read(file_path)
#> Reading layer `pand_c' from data source 
#>   `C:\Users\XXXX\RtmpCOGdcp\pand_c.shp' using driver `ESRI Shapefile'
#> Simple feature collection with 9642 features and 3 fields
#> Geometry type: POLYGON
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 188300.1 ymin: 3060674 xmax: 653718.9 ymax: 3235418
#> Projected CRS: WGS 84 / UTM zone 28N


# Project everything to 4326 for leaflet

canarias_4326 <- st_transform(canarias, 4326)
drought_data_canarias_4326 <- st_transform(drought_data_canarias, 4326)

ggplot(canarias_4326) +
  geom_sf() +
  geom_sf(data=drought_data_canarias_4326, aes(fill=DESER_CLA), color=NA) +
  scale_fill_viridis_c()
```

[image]

```r
library(leaflet)
leaflet(canarias_4326) %>% 
  addTiles() %>%
  addPolygons() %>%
  addPolygons(data = drought_data_canarias_4326)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-05-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: More on this here https://ropenspain.github.io/mapSpain/articles/working_imagery.html and here https://ropenspain.github.io/mapSpain/articles/x02_mapasesp.html#el-caso-canarias

Comment: Thank you a lot! The parameter "moveCAN" solved my problem as I was able to project Canary Island boundaries with the drought data.

Answer (score 0):

responding to your latter comment:

> ("Canary map far away from boundary map")

`esp_get_country()` of library `mapSpain` returns a distorted map: the distance between the Canaries and the Spanish mainland has intentionally be shortended. So, if you plot the Canaries from a separate spatial feature with true coordinates, they won't coincide with the distorted map.

If you want to work with the feature returnded by `esp_get_country` you can do the following:

- split *spain_coun_sf* into separate polygons:

```
spain_fragments <-
    spain_boundary %>%
        st_cast('POLYGON') %>% ## split MULTIPOLYGON into POLYGONS
        ## create polygon IDs for later identification
        mutate(polygon_id = as.factor(row_number())
```

- identify the Canarian polygons using an interactive `ggplotly` plot:

```
library(plotly)
ggplot() + 
  geom_sf(data = spain_fragments , aes(label = polygon_id))
ggplotly()

## I got polygon IDs c(17:18, 20:23, 26:28, 33)
## but better check yourself
```

- create new `sf` containing the Canaries only by selecting the relevant rows of **spain_fragments**:

```
the_canaries <-
    spain_fragments %>%
    filter(polygon_id %in% c(17:18, 20:23, 26:28, 33)) %>%
    st_union

## check:
ggplot() + 
  geom_sf(data = spain_fragments) +
  geom_sf(data = the_canaries, col = 'red')
```

... now you have each Canarian island's boundary for joining with the drought data.